# Reformatting Table Multiple Separators Per Entry

Tags: python, r, bash

I am working on a mac and would prefer to do this reformatting task with Bash, R, or python 3.

Here is a small example of the table that I am working with.  The table is thousands of rows long and each row has variable numbers of columns. Additionally the example contains 12 comma separated values beginning after the Isofrorm_ however i have reduced this to 4 for readability.

```
ENSMUSG0000001234 2.0 Isoform1_0.9,0.0,0.6,1.3 Isoform2_0.1,0.0,0.0,0.5
ENSMUSG0000005555 1.0 Isoform1_0.5,0.1,0.4,1.0 Isoform2_0.7,0.3,0.0,0.1 Isoform3_0.3,9.9,2.0,3.0
```

I would like to be able to search for and reformat a row of interest to the following. To extract the row of interest i can use

```
grep "ENSMUSG0000001234" ./filename
```

But i dont have enough experience to know how to pull out values by position and various separators and organize the output properly.  I think python is probably the best tool for this but i am a python novice.

I need the reformatted entry to look like the following

```
0.9 0.0 0.6 1.3 
0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5
```

For clarity the rownames and column names for this are

```
IsoformID Cell1 Cell2 Cell3 Cell4
Isoform1 0.9 0.0 0.6 1.3 
Isoform2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that your preferred solution would be `Bash`, `R` or `Python 3` but here is a quick solution for your problem that I could provide You in `php`.

You can save the following script into a file eg.: `reformat.php`

```
<?php

$infile = $argv[1];

$handle = fopen($infile, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $data = explode(' ', trim($line));
        print $data[0] . '-' . $data[1] . "\n";
        foreach (array_slice($data, 2) as $row) {
            print str_replace(['_', ','], ' ' , $row) . "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    exit("Unable to open file ($finfile)");
}
```

Then run it from the command line in the following way:

```
php reformat.php your_data_file
```

The script reads and process your file line by line. I am using the first two space separated fields as a block identifier. After then I process the remaining fields (`array_slice($data, 2)`) in the row.

Output:

```
ENSMUSG0000001234-2.0
Isoform1 0.9 0.0 0.6 1.3
Isoform2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5
ENSMUSG0000005555-1.0
Isoform1 0.5 0.1 0.4 1.0
Isoform2 0.7 0.3 0.0 0.1
Isoform3 0.3 9.9 2.0 3.0
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to figure out how to achive the goal using `python`. I came up with the following solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.strip().split(' ')
        print row[0] + '-' + row[1]
        for data in row[2:]:
            print data.replace('_', ' ').replace(',', ' ')
```

This will produce identical output as showed above.